# How to add product category to product meta title?

Tags: magento2, category, category-attribute, meta-title

I have a product called "**Wiper blades 60/50cm**" which is listed in the store Category "**BMW 3 Series e46**" I want to add the Category name to the product meta title so that the meta title becomes "**Wiper blades 60/50cm BMW 3 Series e46**".

I know how to add the Category name to the product name on the frontend page. I don't know how to do it in the meta title. I also know how to add a custom attribute to the meta title. I do it like this in my custom extension:

```
namespace Tnt\MakeModelInMeta\Observer\Frontend\Catalog;

class ProductLoadAfter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {

    /**
    * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
    */
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {

        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        $this->logger->debug(__METHOD__);
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $category = $observer->getEvent()->getCategory();
        if ($product instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product) {
            $pageMainTitle = $product->getData('name');
            $newMetaTitle = $pageMainTitle .$product->getData('make_model');
            $product->setMetaTitle($newMetaTitle);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me add the category name in the way that the attribute "make_model" was added in the meta title.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could put in after on the "layout_generate_blocks_after" event and use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\GroupedCollection. Inside you will find several functions for manipulation. I hope this was useful